# Databse Table Not Creating When Activating The Plugin In Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

$db_name=$wpdb->prefix .'demo1';

function install_plugin()
{

```
    global $wpdb;
    global $db_name;
    $sql="CREATE TABLE".$db_name."(
    `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    );";

    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
```

}

register_activation_hook(**FILE**,'install_plugin');

Comment: You have a typo. Add a space after the `CREATE TABLE`. And I think you want to use your `id` field as a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

because your create table syntax is wrong:

**Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key**

Try following

```
CREATE TABLE ".$db_name."(
    `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );
```